# How to hide/show table rows using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, pagination

I have a Zend Framework (PHP) web application that has a table with a lot of rows.

- 99.9% of the time, the user will take action on the first or second row.
- 00.1% of the time, the user will need to go back and take action on a different row.

So I only really need to display the first few rows on page load, and keep the rest available for the sake of history.

I would like to shorten the table somehow. I'm thinking, using jQuery, maybe do something where the first 5 rows are displayed (the rest are hidden), and at the bottom of the table, there is a link to display 5 more rows.

[alt text http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/2479/5rowtable.png](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/2479/5rowtable.png)

What do you think? How could I achieve this with jQuery?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is how I would do this ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/6Qw7k/)):

Script

```
var numShown = 5; // Initial rows shown & index
var numMore = 5;  // Increment

var $table = $('table').find('tbody');  // tbody containing all the rows
var numRows = $table.find('tr').length; // Total # rows

$(function () {
    // Hide rows and add clickable div
    $table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end()
        .after('<tbody id="more"><tr><td colspan="' +
               $table.find('tr:first td').length + '"><div>Show <span>' +
               numMore + '</span> More</div</tbody></td></tr>');

    $('#more').click(function() {
        numShown = numShown + numMore;
        // no more "show more" if done
        if (numShown >= numRows) {
            $('#more').remove();
        }
        // change rows remaining if less than increment
        if (numRows - numShown < numMore) {
            $('#more span').html(numRows - numShown);
        }
        $table.find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').show();
    });

});
```

Comment: What does the `.end()` do, following the `.hide()` ?

Comment: `.end()` reverts the selection to the previous one... so in this case the selector goes back to `$('table')`. Read more about it here (http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/end), there is also the `.andSelf()` selector (http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/andSelf)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but just in case anyone else is searching I wrote this script:

```
$(function() {
/* initial variables */
var numRows = $('#ticketLinesTable').find('tr').length;
var SHOWN = 5;
var MORE = 20;

/* get how many more can be shown */
var getNumMore = function(ns) {
    var more = MORE;
    var leftOver = numRows - ns;
    if((leftOver) < more) {
        more = leftOver;
    }
    return more;
}
/* how many are shown */
var getInitialNumShown = function() {
    var shown = SHOWN;
    if(numRows < shown) {
        shown = numRows;
    }
    return shown;
}
/* set how many are initially shown */
var numShown = getInitialNumShown();

/* set the numMore if less than 20 */
var numMore = getNumMore(numShown);

/* set more html */
if(numMore > 0) {
    var more_html = '<p><button id="more">Show <span style="font-weight: bold;">' + numMore + '</span> More...</button></p>';
    $('#ticketLinesTable').find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end().after(more_html);
}
$('#more').click(function(){
    /* determine how much more we should update */
    numMore = getNumMore(numShown);
    /* update num shown */
    numShown = numShown + numMore;
    $('#ticketLinesTable').find('tr:lt('+numShown+')').show();

    /* determine if to show more and how much left over */
    numMore = getNumMore(numShown);
    if(numMore > 0) {
        $('#more span').html(numMore);
    }
    else {
        $('#more').remove();
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you could do this with jQuery. I would probably do it this way:

```
<table>
<tbody id="new">
  <tr>...</tr> <!-- x5 -->
  <tr><td><a href="#" id="toggle">Show Old</a></td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="old">
  ...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Load them hidden with CSS:

```
#old { display: none; }
```

and:

```
$(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    if ($("#old").is(":hidden")) {
      $(this).text("Hide Old");
    } else {
      $(this).text("Show Old");
    }
    $("#old").slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

The jQuery hide/show effects can be a bit strange with table components however. If so change the CSS to this:

```
#old.hidden { display: none; }
```

and:

```
$(function() {
  $("toggle").click(function() {
    if ($("#old").hasClass("hidden")) {
      $(this).text("Hide Old");
    } else {
      $(this).text("Show Old");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Of course you don't get the nice effects this way.

Comment: Of course, the downside is you need to load all those rows and then hide them. Wouldn't some ajax thingy be better practice for bandwidth usage? :)

Comment: Agree, and have you noticed StackOverflow does the same client side processing to hide your ignored tags?